# Using Riemann-Roch

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I have canonical divisor $K$ of curve $\mathbb{P}^1$, and  I  would like to find $l(2K)$, $l(3K)$ and $l(-K)$ using Riemann-Roch theorem. I know that $g=0$ in this case, so $deg(K)=2\cdot  0-2=-2$.

My only  idea is  trying something like this
$$l(2K)=deg(2K)+1-g+l(K-2K)$$
I know that $deg(2K)=2deg(K)=-4$ so I get
$$l(2K)=-3+l(-K)$$
but I can't think of a way to get just one of them? After that it is easy to calculate other two.

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible to do just formally using Riemann Roch theorem. Generally, it is quite easy to calculate Euler characteristic (which is generalization of $l(D)-l(K-D)$) but to find $l(D)$ itself is a bit tricky (for example, if have a family of line bundles, their Euler characteristic is constant, but $l(D)$ can jump up in special points).

Comment: Allow me to use the fact, that if degree of divisor is negative, then $l(D)=0$. Then your question is an easy exercise.

Comment: @quinque: Thank you! :D that's it!